# C# Textobox user cannot enter letter

Tags: c#

How to make that when user enter word using given random letters from 12 labels in textbox,user cannot enter letter that does not exist in given letters???
For example if in label is one 'A' he can type it only once,if in labels are two 'D' he can type it only twice.

Answer (score 2):

Employ KeyDown event and implement that logic yourself.

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string pressedKey = e.Key.ToString(); //It will be always uppercase no need for case sensitivity checks
            bool keyNotAllowed;

            // here apply your logic to determine if the key is allowed

            if (keyNotAllowed)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

edit:
  For windows forms, use KeyPressed event, and e.KeyChar parameter.

Comment: Do I need to convert letters to ASCII ?

Comment: No, Just use the string you already have. You can read and write into textBox content by "myTextbox.Text". Read from it, and write on it if necessary.

Comment: converting to ASCII would give you precise control to check the case (lower or upper) etc., if that's not required, you check normally.

Comment: You can use case insensitive comparison instead of dealing with ASCII numbers, by string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

Comment: But when I input that commands I cannot use delete and backspace button and I can input one character multiple times!!!

Comment: Noo, just read the text on textChanged, if you are not happy about the last entered character omit it by
myTextbox.Text= myTextbox.Text.Remove(myTextbox.Text.Length - 1);  and say something to user if you want to.

Comment: You can read the test of textBox by mttextBox.Text.                               String input = mytextBox.Text

Comment: How to know what letters will user type?

Comment: Ok I got you, you need KeyPress event for that TextChanged event will probably occur when user totally submits the input. Do last character check at KeyPress Event. I didn't tried it, but if you want character not to be added, you can say e.handled = true; in this code. That means I handled the input, do not put the character. I will edit my answer for that.

Comment: For example word in labels is "HELLO WORLD",so user can type only: one time letter H and only two times letters LL....He cannot time L three times!!!And what user types must be checked while he types letters!!!

Comment: Ok I edited the answer I guess that will work for you.

Comment: And change the title if you can, there is a typo in it.

Comment: Which platform are you developing on? You have only C# tag. Are you developing a universal app?

Comment: Well than e.Key is perfectly valid. I think you should add uwp tag too, or explicitly tell where you are working on.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer again. Please put some effort before writing everything here, using comments section like as in the chat is not allowed. Edit your question to make it clear. Add that you are developing a forms application for example. Otherwise you get downvoted and will be less likely to get help.